# MySQL - Primary key needed for partition

Tags: mysql

I need to partition my table every day based on UTC timestamp, I am getting error as `Fatal error: A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function`

I am doing this way, column`id` is INT PRIMARY KEY column `date` is INT storing UTC timestamp

My table structure `DESCRIBE stats;`

```
Field   Type    Null    Key     Default     Extra   
id      int(11) NO      PRI     NULL    auto_increment
date    int(11) YES             NULL    
.
.
.
.
```

Create table structure `SHOW CREATE TABLE stats`

```
CREATE TABLE `stats` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 .
 .
 .
 .
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=371 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I execute script via php

```
$today = strtotime("today midnight");
$partition = date('d_m_y',$today); 

ALTER TABLE `stats`
PARTITION BY RANGE (date) (
PARTITION p_$partition VALUES LESS THAN ($today)
)
```

I tried this but getting syntax error

```
ALTER TABLE `stats`
UNIQUE KEY (`id`)
PARTITION BY RANGE (date) (
PARTITION p_$partition VALUES LESS THAN ($today)
)

ALTER TABLE `stats`
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
PARTITION BY RANGE (date) (
PARTITION p_$partition VALUES LESS THAN ($today)
)

ALTER TABLE `stats`
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`date`)
PARTITION BY RANGE (date) (
PARTITION p_$partition VALUES LESS THAN ($today)
)
```

Also tried with `HASH` but same error `A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function in`

```
ALTER TABLE stats
PARTITION BY HASH(date)
PARTITIONS 1
```

Also tried this way but got error `Fatal error: Partition management on a not partitioned table is not possible`

```
ALTER TABLE `stats` 
ADD PARTITION (
PARTITION p_$partition VALUES LESS THAN ($today)
)
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: You are mixing php an sql commands. How do you run the sql commands?

Comment: @Shadow with php script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A primary must include all columns in the table's partitioning location error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896067/a-primary-must-include-all-columns-in-the-tables-partitioning-location-error)

Comment: @TallboY then why on earth did you not fix that error and asked the problem you have **after** fixing? You could have saved so much time for all parties being involved!

Comment: @TallboY you just told both of us that you knew how to fix the partitioning key not being part of the pk error message!

Comment: Let me quote: "@regulus I followed this question before asking here, but didn't worked for me – Tall boY" So, you researched the issue, found the solution, tried to implement it, got another error, but you did ask the original error, and thus wasted our time!

Comment: @Shadow can you see the updates in question and help if you have time?

Answer (score 10):

I solved it by adding `date` to primary key `id`.

```
ALTER TABLE `stats` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(`id`,`date`);
```

Now the table is partitioned successfully.

Hope it helps others too.

Thanks