# Error while I'm trying to partitioning a table

Tags: mysql, partitioning

Here is my `posts` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `img` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `vid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `subtitle` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `auth` varchar(54) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `story` longtext COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `tags` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `status` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `moder` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `rec` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `pos` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `inde` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=117 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_croatian_ci
```

I want to make two partitions in order to improve query performances.
First partition should contain all `non-archive` rows.
Second partition - all `archive` rows.

```
ALTER TABLE posts
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS (status)
(
PARTITION P1 VALUES IN ('admin', 'moder', 'public', 'rec'),
PARTITION P2 VALUES IN ('archive')
);
```

phpmyadmin error:

```
Static analysis:

    1 errors were found during analysis.

    Unrecognized alter operation. (near "" at position 0)
    MySQL said: 

    #1503 - A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function
```

Any help?

Comment: Error says it all. the column you want to partition on, should be part of the primary key.

Comment: update your primary key like PRIMARY KEY (id,status) .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896067/a-primary-must-include-all-columns-in-the-tables-partitioning-location-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What queries are you trying to speed up?  Since the only index you currently have, `WHERE id=...` or `WHERE id BETWEEN ... AND ...`  are the only queries that will be fast.  *And the partitioning you suggest will not help much* for other queries.

You seem to have only dozens of rows; don't consider partitioning unless you expect to have at least a million rows.

`status` has only 5 values?  Then make it `ENUM('archive', 'admin', 'moder', 'public', 'rec') NOT NULL`.  That will take 1 byte instead of lots.

If you will be querying on `date` and/or `status` and/or `auth`, then let's talk about indexes, especially 'composite' indexes on such.  And, to achieve the "archive" split you envision, put `status` as the first column in the index.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestions, very valuable for me. My table will never have a million rows, max about 20.000. Are you really sure that there is no reason for partitioning?

Comment: Suitable indexes are usually as good as or better than partitioning.  More details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint